# Printing and reading lists from a file in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a Clojure data structure of the form:

> {:foo '("bar" "blat")}

and have tried writing them to a file using the various pr/prn/print.  However, each time the structure is written as

> {:foo ("bar" "blat")}

then when I try to read in it using load-file, I get an error such as:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IF
>   n (build-state.clj:79)

presumably as the list is being evaluated as a function call when it is read.  Is there any way to write the structure out with the lists in their quoted form?

thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inverse of printing is usually reading, not loading.

```
user> (read-string "{:foo (\"bar\" \"blat\")}")
{:foo ("bar" "blat")}
```

If you really need to print loadable code, you need to quote it twice.

```
user> (pr-str '{:foo '("bar" "blat")})
"{:foo (quote (\"bar\" \"blat\"))}"

user> (load-string (pr-str '{:foo '("bar" "blat")}))
{:foo ("bar" "blat")}
```